# Loopback relation never return values

Tags: node.js, entity-relationship, loopbackjs, api-design, strongloop

I recently started working with LoopBack to build our own API. It's based on a Mongo DB (pretty new to me too).
I tried to configured multiple relations (I tried different types) and I never get result in the response.
It seems to be properly configured as if I check the Explorer, I see the relation in the example value.

For instance, I have companies, related to one companyGroup as:

```
- Company" Belongsto CompanyGroup
- CompanyGroup hasMany Company
```

Here is my relation configured in my models

**In Company.json**

```
"relations": {
    "companyGroup": {
      "type": "embedsOne",
      "model": "companyGroup",
      "foreignKey": "groupId",
      "primaryKey": "",
      "property": "group"
    }
  },
```

**In company-group.json**

```
"relations": {
    "companies": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "company",
      "foreignKey": "groupId",
      "options": {
        "nestRemoting": false
      }
    }
  },
```

If I check the Explorer, I see the relation configured in the example value :

```
[
  {
    "id": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "groupId": "string",
    "logo": "string",
    "isGroupManager": true,
    "createdAt": "$now",
    "updatedAt": "$now",
    "group": {
      "name": "string",
      "createdAt": "2018-03-08T14:38:51.155Z",
      "id": "string"
    }
  }
]
```

But any response will miss the company group part:

```
{
"id": "5a9ea3fc6d48a58bb619d180",
"name": "Agency (BXL)",
"groupId": "5a9ea3fc6d48a58bb619d17f",
"createdAt": "2018-03-06T14:21:48.322Z",
"updatedAt": "2018-03-06T14:21:48.322Z"
```

},

What did I configured wrong ? Where should I look ? I have an recent updated version of loopback
Thanks !

Laurent

Comment: It doesn't makes sense that `Company` would have `embedsOne` relation to `CompanyGroup`. If you want to use [embedded relations](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Embedded-models-and-relations.html) add a `embedsMany` relation to your `CompanyGroup`. If you want to have regular relations add a `belongsTo` relation to your `Company`.

Comment: So just if I was not clear, I mean a companyGroup (ex: Big Trust Fund) contains multiple companies ("Startup 1, Startup 2, ..."). So when I call Startup 1, I want as embedded the details of Big Trust as a Group child. That's why I set company embedsOne companyGroup (+ companyGroup hasMany companies, as I don't need them returned when I call companyGroup). I thought that belongsTo do not return data, as I didn't get any values whatsoever...

Comment: If `Company` has an `embedsOne` relation to `CompanyGroup` it considers that `CompanyGroup` as part of `Company` i.e. multiple `Campany` models wouldn't share some `CompanyGroup`. Each of them would have their own. I think a `hasMany-belongsTo` relationship is a right way to go. See my comment under the @Karan answer to avoid attaching filter to every query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting group Id in your response and want the group instance in the response too, you can use an include filter.

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Include-filter.html

in your case, you can use a GET like request like the following

```
/api/companies/{comp_id}?filter={"include":{"group":true}}

/api/companies/{comp_id}?filter={"include":["group"]}

/api/companies?filter[include]=group
```

Comment: Thanks Karan, I didn't know that ! It's working like a charm (at least for the only relation I tested out my 20 relations, but no reason it's would not be working for all of them ;) You made my day

Comment: @LaurentParmentier: If you plan to always return your related model in a response, you can create a [default scope](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#default-scope) with an include filter.

Comment: @IvanSchwarz: Thanks, that's a nice option I will definitely use too!